# How to create a function graph in IDA? Could not find grapher (Linux)

Tags: ida, error-messages

IDA (free v8.0 on Kali Linux) produces an error any time I attempt to create a graph, e.g. View > Graphs > Function Call:

> Could not find grapher '/usr/bin/dotty'.  Please check GRAPH_VISUALIZER in ida.cfg
> [image: error msg]

graphviz is installed, and dotty exists in the path indicated.  ida.cfg contains this same path with DOT file type:

```
...
#ifdef __LINUX__
GRAPH_VISUALIZER        = "/usr/bin/dotty"
GRAPH_FORMAT            = "DOT"
...
```

How can I fix this so that IDA can render graphs?

Answer (score 2):

qwingraph is an alternative (and the default) graph viewer for IDA in linux, and it requires installation to function.

Install qwingraph from the site below, and then set ida.cfg to use qwingraph:

```
git clone https://github.com/WqyJh/qwingraph_qt5
cd qwingraph_qt5
sudo ./install.sh
```

ida.cfg:

```
...
#ifdef __LINUX__
GRAPH_VISUALIZER        = "qwingraph -remove -timelimit 10"
GRAPH_FORMAT            = "GDL"
//GRAPH_VISUALIZER        = "/usr/bin/dotty"
//GRAPH_FORMAT            = "DOT"
...
```